# How can I request uer to share their phone number with my Viber-bot

Tags: node.js, viber-bot

Hi I am currently developing a viber bot and i want to request the user to share their phone number with my bot.

I went through docs but was unable to find the answer. Is it possible to ask user to share their phone number if yes how?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.